# Fundamental solutions for weighted laplace equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, green-function

Consider the equation $L_w u = \frac{1}{w}\operatorname{div}(w\nabla u) =f(x)$, on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with radial weights $w(x)=w(|x|).$ Then I am interested in the fundamental solutions for the operator $L_w$.

For instance $w(x)=|x|^\alpha$ for $\alpha>0$ then $L_w u =0$ admits radial solutions of the form $u(r)=c_1r^{2-n-\alpha}+c_2$ when $n\geq 3.$ Then I am guessing that $\frac{c}{|x|^{n+\alpha-2}}$ could be a fundamental solution in this case. Is this true?